# Same Node.js version but gyp build uses different NODE_MODULE_VERSION

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-gyp

I have this project [node-libcurl-impersonate](https://github.com/SwapnilSoni1999/node-libcurl-impersonate)
I've ran `npx node-gyp rebuild` and moved my output to other project which is based on [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)

I've moved the built dist from node-libcurl-impersonate to erb's main folder and used the lib from there and it's showing me the following error

```js
[electronmon] waiting for a change to restart it
App threw an error during load
Error: The module '/home/sonisins/prujekts/node/drivetest-tool/src/main/lib/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl-impersonate.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 103. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1812)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1812)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
    at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.Module._load (/home/sonisins/prujekts/node/drivetest-tool/node_modules/runtime-required/runtime-required.js:34:23)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sonisins/prujekts/node/drivetest-tool/src/main/lib/node-libcurl/dist/Easy.js:5:18)
[electronmon] uncaught exception occured
[electronmon] waiting for any change to restart the app
```

The script in examples/chrome-impersonate.js runs fine after building the lib but not in electron project

Answer (score 1):

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/using-native-node-modules

> Native Node.js modules are supported by Electron, but since Electron has a different application binary interface (ABI) from a given Node.js binary (due to differences such as using Chromium's BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL), the native modules you use will need to be recompiled for Electron. Otherwise, you will get the following class of error when you try to run your app:

Comment: Yes compiled with electron headers and its working 
Thanks. Got figured out couple of days back.